# how to replace data?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Good day.I deduce 50 blocks. Receive information from a file in JSON format.
I get a link to a photo from JSON. I give it to the page. I need to change all the photos large on the small size photos in just one click.
Please tell me how to change the link everywhere at once?

```js
var image = data["info"][i]["img"]["big"];
block += '<img src="' + image + '"/>'; 
//image - link to photo
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm struggling to understand what it is you are actually asking? Are you trying to generate a link from (what I'm assuming) is an image URL represented by 'data['info][i]['img]['big]'?

Comment: Yes, I it generates.Using the ajax, I take out the necessary data is now deduce a large More Photos. I have a filter. There is a button to make the image on the small size of the page. how do I handle this correctly? my code https://codepen.io/zaytsevav/pen/oBQrOm

Comment: Javascript allows you to read properties by a string (`data["info"]`) or using the `.` operator (`data.info`). If you are using a constant property name, it's clearer to use the `.` operator -- `data.info[i].img.big`.

Answer (score 0):

If all the images are displayed inside a single element like this

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img ... >
    <img ....>
    .....
</div>
```

Then you could regenerate the entire contents of the div:

```
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data["info"].length; i++) {
    str += '<img src="' + data["info"][i]["img"]["small"] + '"/>';
}
document.findElementById("gallery").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: each image in a new block. my code codepen.io/zaytsevav/pen/oBQrOm

Comment: So you can use the same code that generated all the blocks again and just replace the big with small. If you put the entire section of code into a function, you could take the imageSize as a parameter to make it more useable.

Comment: did so. in html (  <li><a id="imgMedium" onclick="imgMedium(this)">picture.medium</a></li>  ) ;  in js file function function imgMedium(index){
    var data = results[index];
    var imgM = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        imgM += '<img src="' + data[i].picture.medium + '"/>';
    }
    document.findElementById("user").innerHTML = imgM;
}  I got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: That's because your imgMedium function is expecting an index and you gave it a html element. So results[index] is undefined. I thought you wanted to change all the images sizes at once. The code doesn't work if you just want to change one IMG.